# How to make a container that add shadow according to the shape of widget

Tags: flutter, containers, shadow

I want to add the shadow of the container but make it usable such that if I wrap any widget with this widget it catches the child shape and adds the shadow according to my given oFFSET.
The Code I did so far.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShadowWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  ShadowWidget({this.child});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          offset: Offset(0, 3),
          blurRadius: 6.0,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
        ),
      ]),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Using the Widget

```
ShadowWidget(
                    child: CupertinoSwitch(
                      activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      trackColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color,
                      value: _dhikrSetting,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _dhikrSetting = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

It is getting showing like this.
[image]

Want it like
[image]
Additional add circular color in the switch. how can I change it?

Comment: The way you want to have it dosen't have any shadow, right?

Comment: Yes, the shadow is not there.